# Logitech Wireless H800 Headphones not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, logitech

What have I tried so far?

- I have installed *GNOME ALSA Mixer*, *btsco*, *PulseAudio Volume Control*

I have tried to search with Bluetooth, Cable but it's not showing in Sound while my HDMI port sound display.

[image]

Please let me know if you need to know anything like log, package version etc.

My System specification:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- 64 Bit

Comment: Are you using the nano receiver that comes with it or connecting it to a generic bluetooth adapter (e.g. builtin of a laptop)?

Comment: @TomYan: Yes. I am using builtin of a laptop. Not any third party software or hardware.

Comment: my point wasn't about "third party" but whether you are using the logitech receiver or not. Note that even though both makes use of Bluetooth, if you make use of the the receiver, the bluetooth pairing/connection is done entirely by the hardware so the bluetooth stack of linux is not involved at all (the adapter expose itself to the system as a USB sound card instead of a Bluetooth dongle), which could be way easier and less problematic in linux.

Comment: While if you are using the builtin Bluetooth of the laptop (or any general-purpose bluetooth adapter/dongle), you need to pair/connect the device via bluez and only then would the connected headset be exposed to the system as a sound card (via the modules in bluez-alsa); for that you haven't given any information on what you have tried exactly.

Comment: I have installed and tried version packages as mentioned in question. I have installed as per your suggested package `bluez-alsa`. Would you please provide me information of that how to use it? For Bluethooth pair, I have tried to `Set Up New Device` but my headset is not visible on it. I confirmed that my headset bluethooth is on.

Comment: What about `hcitool scan`?

Comment: Just read the quick start guide, make sure you slide the slider to the middile for bluetooth pairing/connection (i.e. not using the receiver comes with the headset)

Comment: @Odedra Have you tried using the nano receiver? Mine works fine. Well, [mostly fine](https://askubuntu.com/q/890011/301745).

Comment: @wjandrea: in my case, headphones doesn't listed in sound settings under outputs. If we resolve it then I hope resolve others.

Comment: @TomYan: `hcitool scan` give me `Scanning ...` not any result found.

Answer (score 2):

Can you see your headphones in the output from `aplay -l`?

Mine looks like

```
....
card 1: Headset [Logitech Wireless Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Did you try the sound test program:

- `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:1,0`  (with `1,0` changed to necessary to match your listing from `aplay -l`)

Use your *system | sounds | test* function as well if you haven't already.

In the answers to 
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi) question it is mentioned that devices can be secretly muted - Did you check it's not muted?

Ashamed to say it, but I finally got my Logitech USB headphones and HMDI speakers to work by banging on keyboard and trying everything until it it suddenly worked, and I couldn't tell for sure exactly why they started to work.

UPDATE: 9/13/2017

I see from your comment discussion with Tom Yan that you are not using the USB dongle that came with the headphones.  FYI if you lost it you can easily get another generic replacement.  As for using the on-motherboard builtin Bluetooth adapter, you need to understand that there are multiple Bluetooth protocols in existence for different purposes and what you want to do might not be physically possible.(c.f.  [Bluetooth profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_profiles)).  The first question to ask is would it make economic sense for the manufacturer to have added bluetooth headphone capability to an on-board bluetooth adapter?  My *guess* is "no", because **all** headphones already come with dongles.

You've already completed part 1 of the investigation by experimentally seeing if it works out of the box.  If you really think it's worth finding the definitive answer, I would recommend finding out the on-board bluetooth adapter part number, finding the specs for that part, and seeing if they include the protocol for connecting to bluetooth headphones.

IMHO you should have disclosed in your initial question the fact that you were bravely challenging the known limits of bluetooth technology and trying to bypass the dongle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have fired command as per your given. But I can not see my device in that list.

Comment: Do you have the USB dongle plugged into a USB port and have your headphones charged and switched on?  In my case, when the USB dongle was plugged in and the headphones were charged and switched on I could hear a beep indicating that the connection was live, but no sound (music, test patterns, etc.) would be sent to the headphones.

It would be great if you had another system (e.g., a windows pc) to check that dongle-headphones were working and pairing correctly.

Comment: Yes. USB plugged works fine. It charged and light indicator switched on. Right now I don't have window os. But I will check it.

Comment: Just to be clear about my experience: when I had the USB dongle plugged in and put the headphones on, then activated the headphones switch, I could hear a quiet "beep" sound in the headphones and simultaneously the `aplay -l` listing would show the "card 1 , subdevice 0" as in my orig response above - but to get test pattern sounds and application sounds to reach the headset required yet more fiddling around.

Comment: If you can't get that beep sound or the `aplay -l` listing, then you need to solve that first.  Does that USB port work when you plug in a USB drive?   Do other USB ports work?   Are your USB ports properly attached to the motherboard by cables?
If the connection is OK, then you might want to look at device listings to see where that connected device has not been properly pulled up to a higher level by gvfs or fstab.

Comment: `aplay -l` doesn't give me list as per your given `card 1, subdevice 0`. Yes I confirmed that my USB port works fine and my headphones get charged.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Good luck!